# Is there a particular reason to use directional words in a plural form?

Tags: word-choice, plural-forms

By a "directional word", I mean those such as *backward*, *forward*, *toward*, etc. Words specifically indicative of direction of movement. Consider these sentences:

> I walked toward the objective.
>
> The car rolled slowly forward from the garage.

These sentences are clear and grammatically correct. However, I frequently see (and hear) sentences constructed like this:

> The horse galloped towards the barn.
>
> The unicyclist spun over backwards after an ill-considered flourish.

Is there a difference in meaning when these words take a plural ending? Is this another example of infuriatingly lazy English? Is it merely a stylistic choice?